# Aligning an html table across a page with multiple links

Tags: html

I'd like to put some really basic navigation links in a document (running into li:hover problems with ipad).

I've got the following html code, and I'd like to have document header style navigation links

so `Top` would be flush left, the `nav` group would be centered on the top and the `next` would be flush right.

but the content all gets cramped up along the left of the div rather than being spread across it. What am I doing wrong? I would try with css but don't know enough to figure out how to do it.

```
<table id='innav'>
 <col width='20%'/>
 <col width='60%' />
 <col width='20%' />
  <tr> 
    <td align='left'>
        <a href="../index.html">Top</a>
    </td>

    <td align='center'>
        <nav> 
            <a href="./section1.html">Section 1</a>| 
            <a href="./section2.html">Section 2</a>| 
            <a href="./section3.html">Section 3</a> 
        </nav>
    </td>

    <td align='right'>
        <a href="./section1.html">Next</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

EDIT: adding both the table + css version and a pure css version --

the css that makes the above work *very elegantly* is

```
#innav {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0pt;
  padding: 0pt;
}
```

The pure css version that I would have produced - but *looks and feels considerably less elegant* below:

The html is clearly neater and easier to read

```
<ul id='innav1'>
    <li id='leftnav'>
        <a href=".index.html">Top</a></li>
    <li id='centernav'> 
        <ul>
        <li><a href="./section1.html">UK Process</a>|</li>
        <li><a href="./section2.html">NA Process</a>|</li>
        <li><a href="./section3.html">AP Process</a></li> </ul> </li>
    <li id='rightnav'>
        <a href="./section1.html">Next</a> </li> </ul>
```

The css looks like this:

```
#centernav > ul > li {
  display: inline;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0pt;
  padding: 0pt;
}

#centernav {
  width: 30%;
  margin-left: 30%
}

#leftnav {
  float: left;
  width: 7%;
  margin: 0pt;
  padding: 0pt;
}

#rightnav {
  float: right;
  width: 10%
}

#innav1 li{
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

which I'm sure has a few redundant key-values and the final content is much less cleanly distributed across the top of the page.

Given the strong emphasis on a css solution, could someone point me to *why* it would be better and how to make it look as neat as the table solution?

Thanks

Comment: That's so 80's... Have you ever heard about div's, listing's, etc?

Comment: *"What am I doing wrong?"* — You are trying to use tables for layout. CSS 2 came out a decade and a half ago, browsers support it pretty well now.  *"I would try with css but don't know enough to figure out how to do it"* — You can't get table abuse to work for you either, so you have to do some learning either way. Learn CSS instead.

Comment: thanks @Prix. To answer your question - yes. I'm not sure how to apply them effectively here though.

Comment: Thanks @Quentin - Please see my comment to user1671639 below. I do use css extensively, but my css hasn't worked while a small mod to the table approach has. I'd happily adopt a css based approach if a clear way to get the same look and feel were available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would to point the mistake you have made.

It all happened because you haven't given proper width

```
<table id='innav'> <!--MISSED to specify the width of table, it inherit parent-->
<col width='30%'/> <!--Always try to cover 100%, here you have 110% (WRONG)-->
 <col width='60%' />
 <col width='20%' />
```

Change it to

```
 <table id='innav' style="width: 100%"> <!--IMPORTANT, otherwise ti will take BODY-->
 <col width='10%'/> <!-- SPLIT THIS 100% AMONG COL-->
 <col width='80%' />
 <col width='10%' />
```

Check this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/D6GKm/2/)

Second, **`tabular structure` for Navigation quite old.**

Check this [**Sample JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/umaar/YNA5V/) to design using `ul` and `li`s

Check this site to [learn how to build a Nav Menu](http://multimedia.journalism.berkeley.edu/tutorials/css-layout/nav-menu/)

Comment: thanks @user1671639. This is very close to a complete answer and very clearly incorporates the use of a table for the purpose (I've incorporated your comments in my edit. I'm going to wait to see if there are any answers which support the slightly modified question. I think my "I don't know how to do this well in css" was misinterpreted due to my phrasing as "I don't know css" so I'd still like to see if there is a clean css fix that gives me the look I want.

Answer (score 2):

Your markUp could look something like this one:

```
<div class="xyz">
     <ul> 
         <li>
            <a href="../index.html">Top</a>
        </li>
       ...
   </ul>
</div>
```

You can style it via css.
Maybee take a look at [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) framework.

Comment: Thanks @chris the `bootstrap` link is extremely useful. Would be useful to see the actual css if you have an approach which gives the same look as a tabular approach. I'd prefer not to use a framework for this if possible.

Comment: hm, could you give a more specefic example? Do you want a "Flyout-out" navigation with nested lists? The Bootstrap Navbar looks really nice :-) You can use it without writing a lot aof css...

Comment: thanks @chris. I should have been more specific. I already have a css based flyout navigation bar on my page. When I was testing it on an ipad however, I found that the `a hover` property didn't work so I wanted to put simple href links at the top of each page a `home` one on the left, a `next` one on the right, and where it got complicated was I wanted to put a series of related topic links in the centre (usually 2-3). I wanted them to extend all the way across the `div` element too, and they were originally just scrunched up. I'll definitely look into bootstrap :-)

Comment: okay, the css problem is one thing, the hover problem another. Hovering items wont work on the iPad out of the box! Google it, there you will find a solution for this. Maybee a Javascript event handler. Look at the bootstrap navbar (on their website) in small resolutions, it collapses and the links are clickable.